# fetch nested array from mongodb and display in frontend using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Please help me out..

I'm trying retreive data from mongodb using Nodejs
my code is

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/studentprogression';
var str = "";

app.route('/results').get(function(req, res)

    {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            var cursor = db.collection('results').find();
            //noinspection JSDeprecatedSymbols
            cursor.each(function(err, item) {

                if (item != null) {
                    str = str + "  " + item.marks + "</br>";
                }
            });
            res.send(str);
            db.close();
        });
    });

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {});
```

my database in mongodb is

```
{ _id: 5c6935d6b215280be42a6005,
  srn: '01FM17CCA004',
  marks:
   [ { sub1: 'E',
       sub2: 'D',
       sub3: 'A',
       sub4: 'D',
       sub5: 'S',
       taken: 20,
       earned: 20,
       sgpa: 6.95,
       _id: 5c6935d6b215280be42a6006 } ],
  __v: 0 }
```

and output should be data which is inside array (sub1,....sgpa), but im getting as [object Object]

So Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't connect to mongo in HTTP request callbacks, connect to it once and re-use that connection.

```
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

mongoClient.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Available via req.app.locals.db.
  app.locals.db = mongoClient.db('your-database');

  app.listen(3000); 
});
```

Instead of looping over the cursor you can just call `toArray`, I recommend you don't format your data to a string on the server, instead pass the array back as JSON to the client and let the client render it out however it wants:

```
app.route('/results').get(async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = req.app.locals;
  const results = await db.collection('results').toArray();
  res.status(200).json(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your `item` object is not a simple string. it is an array of objects. 
To get the actual object to string, you will have to iterate over it or as Dominic said use the `.toArray()` method to make things simpler. The `[Object object]` comes because you have mapped a whole object to a string.

Also as Dominic said above, please do not make http connections in your request callbacks, connect it before and use the connection to refer to the database.